# Export html content to excel in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am exporting Html content to Excel and download the Excel in JavaScript. It works fine but my requirement is to download Excel without Grid Lines and also I want to render the content as my html shows in browser. Is there any options or suggestions to render Html content in Excel without gridlines?

Below is my sample Html:

```html
<div>
<div style="float:left">
NAME:some text
</div>
<div style="float:right">
Number:some number
</div>
</div>
<div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And my excel sheet:  [image]

I don't want those grid cells and my content is not rendered as Html content.

Is there any way to prepare excel with Html data without gridlines in Javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you just add this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

in the head of the document it will start working as expected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
</script>
```

[Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/cmewv/537/)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, 
its working great than before, but cell A11  need to extend to cell C11 as the data in cell C is last. if any data occupy cell D then Cell A need to ocuppy till cell D. basically need to look like a document in excel
is there any way to apply css  internal or external? .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can update excel files using Apache POI library. Refer https://poi.apache.org/ for more details.

Regarding making the lines disappear, refer http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/how-to-make-the-gridline-disappeared-by-API-td2297448.html

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet");
sheet.setDisplayGridlines(false);
```

More details at [Remove all borders on a specific excel worksheet using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759382/remove-all-borders-on-a-specific-excel-worksheet-using-apache-poi)

Comment: Hey thank for your reply, how to include Apache POI in my webApplication, is there any js file ?

Comment: Nope, there is no JS file. It's a java based library. This needs to be done on the server side or via applet(which is almost dead)